# Python For loop to extract array slow

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following situation.

**getValues()** *Get selenium data and add it to a variable*

**transValues()** *Takes the variable data and makes a simpler array. Because in the variable "temp" there is a .text object*

**comparValues()** *Checks if the variables are the same, if not shows the index.*

**The functions run in 3 different threads simultaneously.**

```
def getValues():
    global names, temp
    while True:
        try:
            names = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "lobby-table__name-container")
            temp = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")
            time.sleep(3)
            vold = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "roulette-history-item__value-textsiwxWvFlm3ohr_UMS23f")
        except:
            pass

def transValues():
    global vatual
    while True:
        try:
            vatual = [x.text for x in temp]
            console_print(vatual[0])
        except:
            console_print("Erro ao transformar valores... persist")
            pass

def comparValues():
    try:
        out = [i for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(vatual,b)) if e1!=e2] or False
        if len(out) > 0:
            print(out)
    except:
        pass
```

The code is so slow:

```
vatual = [x.text for x in temp]
```

Is there another way to do this? temp have 300 keys, this loop takes 3 seconds

Thanks for replying

Comment: Are you sure it's not the time.sleep(3) that's taking three seconds?

Comment: @DonCarleone Yes, I'm using threads, each function is roaming on a different thread. The 3 functions run simultaneously.